# what's the name of a jQuery plugin like this

Tags: jquery

Please see this page:
http://graphicdesignjunction.com/tag/jimgmenu/

What is the name of this plugins? (what we called these?!)
Do you have some examples from this model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one major one that comes to mind, [Kwiks for jQuery](http://www.jeremymartin.name/projects.php?project=kwicks).

[You can check out various demos here](http://www.jeremymartin.name/examples/kwicks.php).  I'm not sure what you'd call the category of plugins, image slider maybe? but that's a bit generic...I'm just aware there there are a few out there, Kwicks being the most mature IMO.